# Hartshorne-Eisenbud cross reference?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a page online that lists where exactly all the algebraic theorems in Hartshorne appear in Eisenbud?  I know that Eisenbud uses the term "codimension" instead of "height", but just Flipping through the chapters on dimension theory, I'm not finding it very easy to locate the particular theorems referenced by Hartshorne.

I'm trying to find the proofs for the dimension theory in the first section, specifically:

- Theorem 1.8A (M, Ch. $5$, $\S14$)
- Theorem 1.11A (A-M, p. $122$)
- Theorem 1.12A (M, p. $141$)

Here "M" refers to Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra* and "A-M" to Atiyah and MacDonald's *Introduction To Commutative Algebra*, which are the references given in Hartshorne.

Comment: I don't know of such a resource, but if you post a list of results in Hartshorne that you would like cross-referenced, I would be happy to help find some of them. (Or maybe giving Hartshorne's references to Matsumura or Atiyah-Macdonald would be easier.)

Comment: I just started Algebraic Geometry.  I'm trying to find the proofs for the dimension theory in the first section: Theorems 1.8A (M Ch.5, sec 14), 1.11A (A-M 1, p. 122), and 1.12A (M p. 141)

Comment: The parts of Eisenbud you want are chapters 8-12. But if you’re just learning algebraic geometry for the first time, it may be best to take those results on faith and look back later. There’s a lot of algebra that goes into these results, and it would take quite some time to grasp.

Comment: I'm just starting "Algebraic Geometry", with capitol letters.

Answer (score 1):

> Theorem 1.8A

Part (a) is Theorem A, $\S13.1$, p. $286$ in Eisenbud:

**Theorem A.** If $R$ is an affine domain over a field $k$, then
$$
\dim(R) = \operatorname{tr. deg.}_k(R),
$$
and this number is the length of every maximal chain of primes in $R$.

The proof is given on p. 289.

Part (b) is Corollary 13.4, p. 286:

**Corollary 13.4.** If $R$ is an affine domain, and $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal, then
$$
\dim(I) + \DeclareMathOperator{\codim}{codim} \codim(R) = \dim(R) \, .
$$

> Theorem 1.11A (Krull's Hauptidealsatz)

Chapter 10, p. 232 of Eisenbud. Here $R$ is a (commutative) noetherian ring.

**Theorem 10.1** (First version of the Principal Ideal Theorem). If $x \in R$, and $P$ is minimal among primes of $R$ containing $x$, then $\codim(P) \leq 1$.

> Theorem 1.12A

Chapter 10, p. 234 of Eisenbud. $R$ is assumed noetherian.

**Corollary 10.6.** A domain $R$ is factorial if every codimension $1$ prime of $R$ is principal.